# Parsing Data Packet to extract wanted data in Python

Tags: python

I'm using this code to read data from a remote xbee:

```
from xbee import XBee, ZigBee
import serial

PORT = 'COM4'
BAUD_RATE = 9600

# Open serial port
ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE)

# Create API object
xbee = ZigBee(ser,escaped=True)
import pprint
pprint.pprint(xbee.api_responses)

# Continuously read and print packets
while True:
    try:
        print "waiting"
        response = xbee.wait_read_frame()
        print response
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

ser.close()
```

The line of code "print response" generates this section of text in command prompt over and over again:

`{'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xe5\x02\x12', 'source_addr': '\xff\xfe', 'id': 'rx_io_data_long_addr', 'samples': [{'adc-0': 210}], 'options': 'B'}`

This is a packet that gets printed in cmd. The data that i need out of each packet is    'samples': [{'adc-0': 210}]  and the number inside of that whcih in this case is 210 but it can range from 0 to 1023. I need to have this number saved in a varable after so that i can use it in a live plot.

I'm still learning how to use python so i.m not exactly sure how to parse data in python. I will appreciate any help with the code to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually parsing data -- `response` is a Python object referred to as a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) (dictionary), and you can reference any element of it.

I believe that `response['samples'][0]['adc-0']` should give you the number you're looking for.

```
print response['samples'][0]['adc-0']
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked an im able print out the live data values. Is there any ways of graphing live data that you could recommend in python?

Comment: I'd recommend asking that as a new question.